# Is it a good practice to namespace jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it a good practice to namespace jobs?

In my application I have two jobs that are related to the `Page` model - both of them are going to receive a post_id and perform a specific task there. The jobs are called `PageWritingScoreJob` and `PageArchitectureScrapingJob`. I want to use the namespace Page instead: `Page::WritingScoreJob` and `Page::ArchitectureScrapingJob`, but not sure if that's a bad practice.

thanks

Comment: Why would it be a bad practice? Rails just lumps everything into the global namespace because its convenient - not because its the best way to build complex software. You have to watch out with the autoloader pre Rails 6 though. It has big problems when you use you classes as a module nesting. Which is why you would more commonly see `Posts::ArchitectureScrapingJob` than `Post::`.

Comment: @max Would love to know more about this, can you point me to some good articles that discuss about this?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh discuss what? If it's the pre Ruby 2.5/ zeitwork issue you can find it here. https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/03/why-you-should-not-use-a-class-as-a-namespace-in-rails-applications/

Comment: @max Could you please post the first response as an answer since it answers the question well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real reason why using namespaces would be a bad practice.

In Rails apps everything is generally lumped in the global namespace not necessarily because it's the best way to do it - it just convenient.

It's a widely accepted that placing code in the global namespace is problematic when it comes to interoperability as it greatly increases the risk of name collisions. This is especially true in Ruby which lacks a import system like that in Python or Ecmascript. That's why almost every gem incapsulates it's constants in a module.

In a rails app though you are most often the end consumer of the application code which means that placing your controllers and models in the global namespace works well enough that it's often worth the trade-off of simpler code templates and not having your code intended an additional step and nested in an additional folder.